# d3.queue never triggers the await function

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, async-await

I am trying to read data from a file with `d3.json`, but the `await()` function never triggers, and I cannot figure out why. I am sure `mapData.json` is present in the folder from which I ran the HTTP server, and no errors are logged in the console.

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, './mapData.json')
  .await(function (error, mapData) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log("Hello");
  });
```

Also, if I replace `queue().defer().await()` with just `d3.json()` (see snippet below), everything works.

```
d3.json('mapData.json')
  .then(mapData => {
    console.log("Hello from d3.json");
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

**UPD:** It seems the problem was with `d3-fetch`. I had the scripts loaded like this:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dsv.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-fetch.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

After commenting out the line containing `d3-fetch`, I got "Hello" logging correctly. Getting "d3.json is not a function" error now.

Comment: I just copy pasted your code in a plunkr and it seems to work fine. Can you re-check if the file is present and if the file is a valid JSON? Here's the plunkr link for reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/aidEF8t62K6uZhJJoi2R?p=preview

Comment: @Shashank Yes, it exists, here's a line from the http server log:
"127.0.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2018 16:48:46] "GET /mapData.json HTTP/1.1" 200 -"
I replaced the contents with {} to be sure, still nothing is being logged

Comment: You are mixing versions. You are first including the D3 **v4** full package, you are then mixing in d3-fetch which is designed to work with v5. That looks really scary and you have witnessed the side effects yourself. Furthermore `d3.queue()` is part of v4 and has been removed from v5. Piecing all these parts together is not going to work. If you want to stick to v4, then remove the references to d3-dsv and d3-fetch modules and your `d3.queue()` is going to work. If you are free to upgrade to v5, also remove the modules' references and use the promise returned by `d3.json()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @altocumulus, that expaines a lot! Do you mind posting the comment as the answer so that others could see it easily in the future?

Comment: If you want `d3.dsv`, `d3.json` and `d3.queue`, just use `d3.v4.min.js`. No further modules needed. If you want v5 instead, use `d3.v5.min.js`. Again, no further modules needed, but no `d3.queue` and different `d3.json`. Including separate modules instead of the full version bundles will further complicate matters. To get you started I recommend you decide on which version to use and get that version's bundle included.